# MySql How Return All Items Which Contain All Selected Features

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, where-clause

```
assigned_features

feature_id      |   item_id
-----------------------------------------------
1               |   1
2               |   1
3               |   1
1               |   2
2               |   2
1               |   3
```

Using mysql, I'm trying to return all items which contain all selected features.

For example, I wish to return items where feature_id = 1 and 2. This should return item_id 1 and 2.

Alternatively, if I only wish to retrieve items where feature_id = 1,2 and 3, the result should yield item 1.

I don't really know where to begin.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
select item_id
from assigned_features af
where feature_id in (1,2)
group by item_id
having count(distinct feature_id) = 2;
```

In similarly you can just increment the count for second example :

```
select item_id
from assigned_features af
where feature_id in (1,2,3)
group by item_id
having count(distinct feature_id) = 3;
```

However, `DISTINCT` is redundant here if `item_id` doesn't have a duplicate `feature_id`s then you can use `count(*) = 2` or `count(*) = 3` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I've learnt something new from you. Thank you!